# Save Exec results in variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I already have a stored procedure `GET_ROW` that is doing a select, according to input ID:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ID = @ID
```

Now, I want to create another stored procedure that checks if an `@ID` exists. If it exists, return the existing row. Otherwise, create a new row with the requested `@ID` and return it.

So, I'm thinking of something like this:

```
Declare ResRow
begin tran
    ResRow = Exec GET_ROW @ID
    if exists (ResRow)
        return ResRow
    else
        Insert into ...
        return Exec GET_ROW @ID
commit
```

After executing this code, I want to be sure that **only one** row with `@ID` exists in the database (no duplicated row with same ID)

Comment: @MartinSmith: That's a weird duplicate close?  This question is about using the result of a stored procedure in another.  The suggested original was about inserting a row if it does not exist.

Comment: @Andomar there is no restriction on implementation in this question that the existing stored procedure has to be used in the new stored procedure. The actual requirement is to only insert a row that does not exist. The answers in the duplicate cover this topic well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create table variable in first and then use following query:

```
Declare @T Table(Col1 int, Col2 int ,...)

Insert Into @T
Exec Get_Row @ID

Select * From @T
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertOrFetch @ID INT
AS 
BEGIN 
   -- check if it doesn't exist yet
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE ID = @ID)
      INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(ID)
      VALUES (@ID)

   -- now return the row
   SELECT TOP (1) *
   FROM dbo.MyTable
   WHERE ID = @ID
END
```

If you first check if the row doesn't exist it, and if so, insert the new data - then the `SELECT` afterwards will always return the row (pre-existing or newly inserted) to you.

Comment: This does not prevent duplicates at default isolation level.

Comment: @MartinSmith: if the `ID` is the table's primary key (which is kinda what I expected here), it would since the PK must be inherently unique .

Comment: The last sentence of the question indicates this may not be the case.